# NUL character in xml file (using dom4j)

Tags: xml, dom4j, nul

I am using dom4j to extract information in xml files(all in one folder).
Here's my code:

```
    File folder = new File("c:/folder directory");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    FileOutputStream foutstream = new FileOutputStream("c:/mozilla_expertlist.txt",true);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(foutstream);
    
    for (File file: listOfFiles)
    {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        File f = new File("c:/Users/dahuo2013/workspace/mozilla_xml/"+file.getName());
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        reader.setEncoding("utf-8");
        Document doc = reader.read(f);
        Element root = doc.getRootElement(); 
        Element foo;
        
        for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator("bug"); i.hasNext();) 
        { 
            foo = (Element) i.next();
            writer.println(foo.elementText("assigned_to"));
        }
        
    }
    writer.close();
```

My code is working however it always have errors reporting. Then I found that when the xml file has NUL NUL NUL characters. It shows error. When I delete those NUL characters. It will definitely work.

But I have more than 4000 xml files in the folder.I cannot delete those NUL one by one by my hands. My xml is encoded by utf-8. Is there any easy way to avoid those NUL characters? Or what kind of easy solution can delete those NUL characters?

Thanks!

also:

[image]

This is the NUL character. I opened in notepad++

Comment: Before you go deleting the `nul` bytes wholesale you should try to find out why they're there.  Is the file encoded in UCS-2 or UTF-16?  It may be that you are using the wrong input encoding.  Can you post a sample of the input file showing the `nul`s? How about a hex dump of the file showing the invalid characters?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I extracted the file directly from website(bugzilla). Here's the header:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE bugzilla SYSTEM "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=bugzilla.dtd">

<bugzilla version="4.2.7+"
          urlbase="https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/"
          
          maintainer="bugzilla-admin@mozilla.org"
>

Comment: What is the URL you used to extract it?

Comment: @JimGarrison here's my python code:values = {'ctype': 'xml', 'excludefield': 'attachmentdata', 'id':list}
                req = requests.post('https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi',data=values)
                print req.text

Comment: @JimGarrison also writer.write(req.text.encode('utf-8')) I encoded in utf-8   I was using requests package of python.

Comment: @JimGarrison Please take a look the image I added which shows the NUL character when I opened in notepad++

Comment: I suggest your problem is in your Python code.  You are somehow corrupting the data while receiving it and/or writing it to the file.  You should probably delete this question and write a new one about the Python code instead.